# jQuery check if any div on page has specific class in an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm using Bootstrap switch https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch and have a few switches in a table.

When a switch is toggled I check the state of the switch and have a basic if condition. When the data.value is false the switch has been turned off. I tried to run another conditional to check if any of the switches in the table, had the `switch-on` class, and if so hide a series in high charts. This isn't working as expected. I'm pretty sure my selector is ok `div.make-switch > div` is selecting the first nested div, which has the class `switch-on` or `switch-off`

Whats wrong with the code? Shouldn't my second if condition fire every time the switches are turned off and check if any of the switches are on?

Thanks

The HTML rendered by the on and off states is below,

```
if(data.value == true){
// Switch is on
}
else if (data.value == false){
// Switch is off

    if ($('div.make-switch > div').hasClass('switch-on')){

        series.hide();
    }
}
```

Off state has class `.switch-off` in nested div

```
<div class="make-switch switch-mini has-switch"><div class="switch-off switch-animate"><input name="" id="create-switch" type="checkbox"><span class="switch-left switch-mini">ON</span><label class="switch-mini" for="create-switch">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right switch-mini">OFF</span></div></div>
```

On state has class `.switch-on` in nested div

```
<div class="make-switch switch-mini has-switch"><div class="switch-on switch-animate"><input name="" id="create-switch" type="checkbox"><span class="switch-left switch-mini">ON</span><label class="switch-mini" for="create-switch">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right switch-mini">OFF</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('div.make-switch > div.switch-on').length) {
```

If an element exists that matches the selector, the `length` property will return a "truthy" result.

Comment: In what this is different of OP's code: `if ($('div.make-switch > div').hasClass('switch-on'))` ?

Comment: @A.Wolff i'm also curious why my code wouldn't work correctly. Jason P this did work and i'll mark it as the answer as soon as i'm allowed

Comment: @A.Wolff Good point, his code works: http://jsfiddle.net/8VEQ7/. I assumed initially that `hasClass` checked the first item in the collection, but it looks like that was an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @JasonP .hasClass() returns true if at least one element match selector, .is() works the same. It's can be confusing for sure